# RoR: Error handle to validates_uniqueness_of example

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My RoR app currently reads in csv file and imports a lot of data. One my model's attribute is validated for unique (set validates_uniqueness_of) and data for that attribute can not be repeated. However, how can I let the repeated data just pass, rather than show error page? I'd like the file reading process to continue running while simply ignoring the repeated data.

Comment: Can you add to your question what you currently have? Are you doing this through a `seed.rb` file? Are you using a type of CSV importer?.

Comment: The issue is solved by replace create! method to new+save. And I use if condition to control, if save return false, just ignore.

Comment: If you've solved your issue, post it as an answer and accept it, so anyone who has a similar issue can use your solution for guidance.